# S3 classes in R: How to properly define a super- and its subclass?

Tags: r, oop

I try to construct a toy example (for educational purposes) of inheritance in the S3 paradigm. I want to
construct a class "Distribution" of general distributions and then a subclass
"Gamma" for all gamma distributions. The flexibilty of S3 allows to do that in
various ways, below are two and I wonder what's the 'preferred'/better/cleanest/standard approach to implement such an inheritance example (if it's a third approach, I'd be happy to hear about it, too).

```
## Version 1:

## Superclass of (univariate) distributions
distribution1 <- function(x, univariate = TRUE, ..., class = character(1))
    structure(x, univariate = univariate, ..., class = c(class, "Distribution"))

## Subclass of gamma distributions (with 2 parameters)
gamma1 <- function(params)
    distribution1(list(name = "Gamma", shape = params[1], rate = params[2]),
                  class = "Gamma")

## Example
myGa1 <- gamma1(c(1,2))
class(myGa1)
myGa1


## Version 2:

## Superclass of (univariate) distributions
distribution2 <- function(name, univariate = TRUE) {
    x <- list("name" = name, "univariate" = univariate)
    structure(x, class = "Distribution")
}

## Subclass of gamma distributions (with 2 parameters)
gamma2 <- function(params) {
    dist <- distribution2("Gamma")
    dist <- c(shape = params[1], rate = params[2], dist)
    structure(dist, class = c("Gamma", "Distribution"))
}

## Example
myGa2 <- gamma2(c(1,2))
class(myGa2)
myGa2
```

Version 2 is what I started with and I found it 'natural'. After reading [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-inheritance), I came up with Version 1. I am wondering what people with experience in inheritance problems would prefer/do/use. For example, is it bad practice to call structure() twice in Version 2 and one should really call the constructor of the superclass to make sure the inheritance is (conceptually) not messed up? (because if gamma2 doesn't manually assign the two classes correctly, the inheritance isn't properly captured). Another point is whether arguments like `univariate` should be stored as attributes (as in Version 1) or as part of the object `x` (as in Version 2)? Since attributes can get lost, I feel Version 2 is preferred there, but I'm missing the experience to say whether modifying `x` or rather leaving `x` as is and modifying attributes of it is to be preferred.

Comment: Design decisions are really just opinion based questions which are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. There's no clear interpretation of preferred/better/cleanest. That's pretty subjective. Do you have an object criteria that you want to test a given solution with? Otherwise just use whatever you feel most comfortable maintaining in the long run.

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't know that it's on topic. It's difficult to know what a formal non-opinion based answer would be here. Your second method looks pretty idiomatic to me. It allows generic dispatch on functions that apply to all univariate distributions (such as a `plot.distribution` method) but you can specialise for other methods like `print.gamma`. However, I have to agree with @MrFlick here - there is no canonical answer

Comment: Just added a comment below the original post. I know this is partly subjective (perhaps less so with S4), but I still find it a suitable question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not convinced the question is concrete enough to have a definitive answer, but I thought it was worth pointing out that if a "bare" `Distribution` class doesn't make sense, you don't need a class constructor for `Distribution` at all. You can still make use of generic dispatch on the class. For example, suppose we have both `gamma` and `normal` classes which inherit from `Distribution`, even though there is no constructor for the superclass.

```r
gamma <- function(shape = 1, rate = 1) {
    params <- list(shape = shape, rate = rate)
    funcs <- list(r = "rgamma", d = "dgamma", p = "pgamma", q = "qgamma")
    structure(list(params = params, functions = funcs), 
              class = c("Gamma", "Distribution"))
}

normal <- function(mean = 0, sd = 1) {
    params <- list(mean = mean, sd = sd)
    funcs <- list(r = "rnorm", d = "dnorm", p = "pnorm", q = "qnorm")
    structure(list(params = params, functions = funcs), 
              class = c("Normal", "Distribution"))
}
```

But we want them to have a common `print` method, we can do:

```
print.Distribution <- function(obj, ...){
  cat("A", class(obj)[1], "distribution",
      "with the following parameters:\n")
  print(obj$params)
}
```

We could also dispatch according to their specific classes, or indeed just use their members to dictate the behaviour of functions that act on them:

```
sample_from <- function(obj, n) {
  obj$params$n <- n
  do.call(obj$functions$r, obj$params)
}
```

So testing, we have

```
G <- gamma(2, 2)
N <- normal(2, 2)

G
#> A Gamma distribution with the following parameters:
#> $shape
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $rate
#> [1] 2

N
#> A Normal distribution with the following parameters:
#> $mean
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $sd
#> [1] 2

sample_from(G, 5)
#> [1] 0.8004810 0.5379604 0.6664775 1.4265927 0.3906471

sample_from(N, 5)
#> [1] -0.88467860  2.22021492  0.04888023  1.20121689  0.77439298
```

Comment: Thanks, Allan, that was the type of 'insight' I was looking for. I guess with a superclass `Distribution`, the idea is that it's 'cleaner' -- you'd not have to remember to give a new distribution the class `class = c("<whatever>", "Distribution")` (but just `class = "<whatever>"`) as the class `Distribution` would simply be inherited.